# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null, fetched URL

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've some issues when I am trying to fetch the data and render in ReactFullpage Component.

The error says: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

Since in the attached script he will get the data from the row here is an example for the var url = https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07YD776RP?ref=myi_title_dp

```js
// script for scraping amazon data outgoing from an url

function import_amazon_data() {
  
//go to Google Sheet & get new income form column 4 
  var scraperSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("product_seller_data")
  
  var lrow =  scraperSheet.getLastRow();

  for(var i=2;i<=lrow;i++){
  
    var url = scraperSheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue() 

    var regExprice = /<span id="priceblock_ourprice.*<\/span>/gi 
    var regExsellername = /id=['"]sellerProfileTriggerId['"]>.*?<\/a>/gi
    var regEximgsrc = /data-old-hires=".*?"/gi

    var getContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText().trim();

//match of HTML elements with fetched URL
    var price = getContent.match(regExprice)
    price = price[0]
    price = price.replace('<span id="priceblock_ourprice" class="a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockBuyingPriceString">',"")
     .replace('</span>',"")
     
    scraperSheet.getRange(i, 6).setValue(price) 
    
    var sellername = getContent.match(regExsellername)
    sellername = sellername[0]
    sellername = sellername.replace("id='sellerProfileTriggerId'>","")
        .replace('id="sellerProfileTriggerId">',"")
        .replace('<\/a>',"")
     
    scraperSheet.getRange(i, 7).setValue(sellername)
     
    var imgsrc = getContent.match(regEximgsrc)
    imgsrc = imgsrc[0]
    imgsrc = imgsrc.replace('data-old-hires="',"")
        .replace('"',"")
     
     scraperSheet.getRange(i, 5).setValue(imgsrc)
     
    
}

 
}
```

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: The Error is on line 24.
I already saw, that amazon changed his span id for the price into this:

<span id="price_inside_buybox" class="a-size-medium a-color-price">
67,99&nbsp;€
</span>

But even if I change the reg. expression in my script, it still cannot find the price in the fetched url.

Maybe I did something wrong with the expression for the var regExprice??
This is how it looks now:

var regExprice = /<span id="price_inside_buybox.*<\/span>/gi

Comment: `The Error is on line 24.` if I paste your code into an editor there is no part which trys to access element `[0]` of a variable on line 24. What is the line? The code? I got no errors when I ran it so without your sheet I can not mimic your setup. Can you [please provide all necessary information](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce your situation otherwise there is no way we can help.

Comment: Here is the Link to my google drive:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vbc4TfnFLUvRgY_-hDqsadZ9f6CL5xuf?usp=sharing

Comment: Please change the sharing settings as it is currently unviewable.

Comment: So sorry, now it should work: 

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vbc4TfnFLUvRgY_-hDqsadZ9f6CL5xuf?usp=sharing

Comment: Well it appears that the page doesn't have any item with the ID `price_inside_buybox`. Not sure where you got that from but that's why you get the error. See Rafik Farhad's answer for how to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

Place a check before accessing these arrays: `price[0], sellername[0]` and `imgsrc[0]`.

To check in development you may use

```
if(Array.isArray(price) && price.length > 0) {
   price = price[0];
} else {
    alert('Price array is empty')
}
```